# Session lost after redirection from payments provider codeigniter

Tags: php, curl, codeigniter-3, libcurl, php-curl

Some of our customers are experiencing a strange situation in which they loose their session data. This always happen after a redirect from our payments privider ogone. The flow is a following:

- The user is completing  it's order
- The user decides to pay through ogone.
- Afterwards the user is redirected to the application's payment success / error handler.

While debugging this issue, I found out that the session data is lost when the user is redirected from ogone to the application. This happens only once on x amount of requests. So when I test the code in any possible browser, it appears to work just fine. I did not manage to find a link between failed payments and browser / payment method / ....

This is my session configuration:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 172800;//48 hours
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = false;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

The first step is to confirm the card with the bank

```
 try {
        $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/xml', 'Content-length: ' . strlen($xml)));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
                 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://boatest.kuveytturk.com.tr/boa.virtualpos.services/Home/ThreeDModelPayGate'); 
                
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
               
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
                
                 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name() . '=' . session_id());
                $data = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            }
```

The visitor is diverted to an external page to set the SMS payment verification code Then
The second step is to Confirm the payment

```
 try {
                    
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/xml', 'Content-length: ' . strlen($xml)));
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
                  
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://boatest.kuveytturk.com.tr/boa.virtualpos.services/Home/ThreeDModelProvisionGate'); //Baglanacagi URL
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
                  
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
                   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name() . '=' . session_id());

              

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
                $data = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                
                $xxxml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            }
```

When it is switched to the second step, session data is lost

Can you help with this

Note that this problem does not occur permanently sometimes for some users

Comment: can you please confirm your CI-version? there have been reported some session issues with early 3.x versions

Comment: ci-version = 3.1.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

header('Set-Cookie: ' . session_name() . '=' . session_id() . '; SameSite=None; Secure');